# Laravel handle complicated request

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I have a request that sends a FormData to my API.

It has following structure:

```
image: file type image;
text: 'some long string';
array: ['string', 'string'];
data: [
  { field: 'string', link: 'url' },
  { field: 'string', link: 'url' },
]
```

I successfully handled first three inputs but stuck with the last one.

Laravel receives it as an array of strings instead of an array of objects.

I'm not able to access fields neither via `$request->data->field` nor via `$request->data['field'}`

Also I tried to use `json_decode` but this returns `null`

## Update #1

```
array(4) {
  ["text"]=>
  string(17) "asdajsklfsdnfnads"
  ["array"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "sadasd"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "safsdf"
  }
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(39) "{link: "http://sdf.sdf", field: "asfd"}"
    [1]=>
    string(44) "{link: "http://sdf.sasdf", field: "asasdfd"}"
  }
  ["image"]=>
  object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)#787 (7) {
```

Comment: what is result `dd($request->all())`;

Comment: @Davit updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$result = [];
foreach($request->data as $data) {
   $object = json_decode($data);
   $result[] = $object;
   // $object['filed'] you can access in field attribute 
}

dd($result);
```

Comment: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  NULL
}`

Comment: For now solved for Postman changing `field` to `"field"` and so on. Now I'll try it in my Angular app

Comment: data structure must be similar this `{"link": "http://sdf.sdf", "field": "asfd"}`

Comment: that's from the Postman. In the Angular app it uses `JSON.serialize()`. Now it works. Most of the misunderstanding was caused by postman and absent of quotes